# Two-thirds or two-third share?

Tags: grammar, fractions

Please, if I say four-wheel-drive, can I say two-third share?
Thank you

Comment: Two-third share

Comment: If you're **saying** it, either one is fine, because no one can hear the difference anyway. If you're **writing** it, it depends on the context and the punctuation. If you hyphenate it, though, either one will work with an article: both _a two-third share_ and _a two-thirds share_ mean the same thing: a share consisting of 2/3 of whatever's being divided.

Comment: Thanks very much, John! Very clear!